# Text needs in exact center Horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I need to create something like: Text should come in exact middle position horizontally and vertically. I've achieve horizontally, but having problem in vertically. As, my text is dynamic. Sometime it is two line of text , sometime its four line or sometimes its only one line.

Here is my CSS CODE:

```
.image-container { border:1px solid #CCC; height:300px; width:300px; position:relative; float:left; margin-left:20px; }
p {position:absolute; top:40%; text-align:center; width:100%; }
```

Here is a html :

```
 <div class="image-container">
<p> One line Content works perfact</p>
 </div>
 <div class="image-container">
<p> Two line Content:Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </p>
 </div>
 <div class="image-container">
<p> Three Line Content:Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
 </div>
```

Please find the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/YK7V5/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to go with `display:table` and `display:table-cell` technique:

**css**

```
.image-container{
  display:table;
  border:1px solid #CCC; 
  height:300px; 
  width:300px; 
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;
 }
p {
 display:table-cell;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK7V5/1/)

Also take a look here:

[6 Methods For Vertical Centering With CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)

Answer (score 3):

Hey tested this in you fiddle and it works :)

```
.image-container { border:1px solid #CCC; height:300px; width:300px; position:relative; float:left; margin-left:20px; }
    p {text-align:center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 300px; width: 300px;}
```

Hope it works for you :)